# JSPDF won't create a PDF in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, jspdf

I'm calling a page that uses jspdf (1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js) to create a PDF. It works fine in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge. But when I access the page in IE11, it just sits there and doesn't create the PDF. Nothing appears in the IE View Downloads window.

The intent is to generate a pure PDF, not embed it into an HTML doc, and I am forced to accommodate IE11 because our customers use it.

Any Suggestions?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var doc = new jsPDF('landscape', 'mm');
        var imgData = "data:image/jpeg;base64, <?=$logo;?>";
            doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 250, 15, 30, 30); // logo image

            doc.setFont("times", "bold");
            doc.setFontSize(32);
            doc.text("Certificate of Achievement",144,35, "center");

            doc.setFont("times", "normal");
            doc.setFontSize(20);
            doc.text("awarded to",144,45, "center");

            doc.setFont("times", "bold");
            doc.setFontSize(34);
            doc.text("John Q. Public",144,65, "center");
        doc.save('training_certificates.pdf');
```

Comment: FYI I used base64_encode in PHP to create the $logo variable.

Comment: I tried to test your code with the [official demo](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa7Cq.png. It can work well in IE and downloads the pdf file successfully. Is there any error in console in IE? Is there anything wrong with the base64 data?

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with the base64 data, as it works fine in Chrome/Firefox/Edge. The images are both local to the server where the script runs, and both are accessible (permissions-wise.)

Comment: The IE console doesn't reveal any errors, either. No feedback whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

What about try [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yuzhou0602/6qywksLx/1/) in IE to see if it triggers the download? I used the data in the official demo and used the functions you providing in your code sample. It works well in my **IE 11.116.18362.0**, **Update Versions: 11.0.126**. What is your IE version?

If it can trigger download in IE, then it might be something special with `<?=$logo;?>` in IE. You could compare the data outcome in IE with in other browsers to see if there's any difference.

If it still can't trigger download in IE, then I think there might be something wrong with your IE browser. You could check **Internet** **Options** -> **Security** -> **Internet** or **Local intranet** -> **Custom level** -> **Downloads** -> **File download**, set it to **Enable**, then click **OK**, **Apply**, then restart IE and try again. If it still doesn't work you could try to [reset](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings) or [reinstall](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318378/how-to-repair-or-reinstall-internet-explorer-in-windows) IE to see if it helps.

Comment: Running IE 11.1622.16299.0, your demo works. I used file_get_contents and base64_encode to encode the graphic within PHP, that would appear to be where the problem lies. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: It seems that you have found the issue. You could put your solution as an answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues.

Comment: Where the issue appears to be is not the same as finding the solution. I still haven't figured out how to convert to base64 in such a way that IE understands.